# how can I change the position of html text?

Tags: html, css, css-position, webfonts

I'm new to web development.
here is my html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {errors}
        <p>Enter your numbers:</p>
        <form method="post" action=".">
            <p><input name="number1" /></p>
            <p><input name="number2" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see how it appears below:

[image]

How can I change the position and font and size? it is currently being shown at the top left corner.

Comment: Try moving around the HTML code or CSS positioning. [`font-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) properties can help with the font and size.

Comment: Use CSS with `font-size` and `text-align`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On web development, any time you need to style an element of your page, you need to use CSS. Have a look at [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) if you want to learn more about it.

In this case I'm going to show you how to apply internal styles, but you can apply CSS with external or inlined styles as well - Have a look [here](https://www.hostpapa.co.uk/knowledgebase/understanding-external-internal-inline-css-styles/#:%7E:text=An%20external%20stylesheet%20is%20a,linked%20from%20a%20web%20page.&text=Again%2C%20a%20single%20change%20to,style%20a%20specific%20page%20element.) for an explanation of it.

```html
  <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: 'Calibri', 'sans-serif';
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-align:center;
                }

                form {
                    position: relative;
                    bottom: 0;
                    right: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            {errors}
            <p>Enter your numbers:</p>
            <form method="post" action=".">
                <p><input name="number1" /></p>
                <p><input name="number2" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So in here, I gave you an example of how to use:

- font-family - used to change the font type
- font-size - to change size of the font
- font-weight - to change the thickness of the font
- position - used to position your element differently, by combining it with the use of top, left, right and bottom attributes
- See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) to know more about CSS font styles
- See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to know more about CSS positioning

Comment: why you not attached snippet with code.... @ale917k

Comment: it will be better to understand for new html,css developers.

Comment: thanks a for your answer, I'm a beginner and the sources you sent are helpful.
when I replaced the code you sent with my code I received an error: 
KeyError: '\n                        font-family'

Comment: Mm not so sure why that happens to be honest - Do you have a shareable link with the reproduced issue? You can create one with jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ and then share it back so I can help you to debug it :)

Comment: I created one: https://jsfiddle.net/x459j3em/
there is an error here too.
by the way, I am using Flask to creat my website. it completely works but it's appearance is bad.

Comment: I think this problem has something to do with my code.
should I import anything to be able to use styles in Flask?

Comment: I never used flask so I cannot help you with using it, you may want to create a question on a side for that. Anyway in order to make styles with css work, you only need the piece of html I provided you, but if you apply specific frameworks like flask, in most cases you have variations on the sintax. You may find useful these links: https://pythonhow.com/add-css-to-flask-website/ https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/, but this is anyway getting out of topic.